# How to perform univaraiate Analysis in Python using Plots

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset below and I wanted to perform univariate analysis on `Income` `Category` as the sample plot shown. Here the point is in the Number category `1` is treated as `Male` and `0` is treated as `female`.
Is there any way possible to solve this.

```
Income  Population  Number  Category
54        77           1       A
23        88           1       A
44        87           0       B
55        88           0       B
66        89           1       B
73        90           0       A
12        89           1       C
34        9            0       C
54        77           1       A
23        88           1       A
44        87           0       B
55        88           0       B
66        89           1       B
73        90           0       A
12        89           1       C
34        9            0       C
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem you have?

Comment: I am not able to separate the `1` as `Male` and `0` as `Female` and plot the following graphs for different variables.

Comment: Put your dataset in a `DataFrame`. You can then read [this](http://walkerke.github.io/geog30323/slides/eda-1/#/) for instance, it will help you.
To separate `Male` and `Female` you need to learn [indexing and selecting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).
You could do for instance `df[df.Number==1]` to get a `DataFrame` with only `Male` and then plot whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if your question is clear. But, followings plots are commonly used to perform univariate and bivariate analysis.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Income': [54,23,44,55,66,],
                   'Population':[77,88,87,88,89],
                   'Number':[1,1,0,0],
                   'Category':['A','A','B','B','C']})

### Univariate analysis
sns.distplot(df.Income) # numeric
sns.boxplot(df.Income) # numeric
sns.distplot(df.Population)
sns.countplot(df.Category) # categorical
sns.countplot(df.Number)

## Bivariate analysis
sns.jointplot('Income', 'Population', data = df, kind='scatter')
sns.lmplot(df.Income, df.Population, data=df, hue='Number', fit_reg=False)
sns.countplot(Category, hue = 'Number', data=df)

## Multivariate analysis
sns.pairplot(df.select_dtypes(include=[np.int, np.float]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the data into a pandas DataFrame then you can get the easily separate out the values for Males and Females, e.g. (just using `Income` and `Number`):

```
import pandas as pd
# a dictionary of the data
data = {'Income': [54, 23, 44, 55, 66, 73, 12], 'Number': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]}
# put the data into a pandas DataFrame
d = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# get a list of Income for the Males
incomem = d['Income'][d['Number'] == 1].tolist() # you don't really need the tolist() call

# get a list of Income for the Females
incomef = d['Income'][d['Number'] == 0].tolist()
```

You can then plot a bar graph using, e.g. the example [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/barchart_demo.html). The plot.ly package also looks nice for this sort of thing, as in the example [here](https://www.kaggle.com/bekaaa/univariate-analysis-using-plot-ly-in-python).